# Difference between model score on test part and Kaggle public score

Tags: cross-validation, kaggle, validation, score, catboost

I tested my CatBoostModel model on part of data and get 0.92 score, but Kaggle public score was 0.9. I found new hyperparameters via randomsearch, new model score was 0.925, but on Kaggle score fell to 0.88.

What should I do to validate the model correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you should expect to get lower scores on test sets than validation sets, since you took advantage of validation data to tune your model. But for a correctly trained model, the difference between the validation and test sets must be small, as in 0.92 vs 0.9. To be more confident about your model's output, you can perform [Cross-Validation](https://www.kaggle.com/alexisbcook/cross-validation).

Also, apparently, your model overfitted the training data after hyperparameter optimization. You can use [regularization](https://towardsdatascience.com/regularization-in-machine-learning-76441ddcf99a) or [early-stopping](https://www.kaggle.com/ryanholbrook/overfitting-and-underfitting) to prevent that.